# How do I call a method which is present inside a static class?

Tags: java

I'm very new to Java programming and I have a doubt.

I have a program like this:

```
class A {

  static final class B {

       public int addMe() {
       }

  }

}
```

how do I call the method `addMe`?

When I do `A.B.addme()` I get an error.

Comment: Correct your compile error in `B`. Also, did you mean to make the method in `B` static?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`addme()` is an instance method of the inner class B. So you need a B instance to be able to call it:

```
A.B b = new A.B();
b.addme();
```

Comment: Why A.B? It's a static class, so you can just write `B b = new B()`

Comment: No, not if you don't have a static import for A.B.

Comment: @DariuszWawer you can do that only in class A. Outside A, you need to follow what JBNizet typed.

Answer (score 3):

Your `addMe()` method is not static, so you can't call it without `B` class instances:

```
A.B b = new A.B();
b.addMe();
```

Answer (score 1):

Typical java inner class (without static) can be initialized only inside the class it is declared in. A static inner class is actually a normal class, visible to any other class in the program, but declared in other class' file.

You have to instantiate the static class B and call the method or mark the method itself as static.